# Crystal Report Formula to count number of occurrences

Tags: crystal-reports

Ηow to resolve this issue? Ι have the following records:

```
|ID  |  Status    |
|----|------------|
|1   |  GOOD      |
|2   |  MODERATE  |
|3   |  MODERATE  |
|4   |  BAD       |
|5   |  GOOD      |
```

I want to get the following in Group section :

```
GOOD(2) - MODERATE(2) - BAD(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Create two formula's

```
Formula 1: {Table.Status}
```

```
Formula 2: {Table.ID}
```

**Step 2:** Create a Group
Depending on the Crystal Reports version you have

- Click on Reports located in the tab.
- Click on Group Expert
- Then group by Formula 1 i.e. {Table.Status}

**Step 3:**

Place the two formula's in the Group Footer. This should give you the count of Status i.e. Good, Moderate, and Bad.